# How to create a custom sphinx directive that uses the image directive?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I need to display a bunch of image that are stored in a json file (the list of our sponsors) like this:

```json
{
  "toto": "path/to/image",
  "tutu": "path/to/image",
  ...
}
```

I have colleagues that are not very good at rst and asking them to write an extra image directive is too much. To help them I would like to create a custom directive that parse the json file and then "calls" the image directive. is it possible ?

I would write something like:

```
.. logo:: path/to/json
```

and that's all.

What I already try is a fully customized directive but it only works in html and instead of creating extra visit_method I would like to add images node for each image in the list.

```py
"""Logo extention to create a list of logos"""
import json
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Dict, List

from docutils import nodes
from sphinx.application import Sphinx
from sphinx.util import logging
from sphinx.util.docutils import SphinxDirective, SphinxTranslator

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

SIZES = {"xs": 6, "sm": 8, "md": 10, "lg": 12, "xl": 15, "xxl": 20}
"Accommodate different logo shapes (width values in rem)"


class logo_node(nodes.General, nodes.Element):
    """Logo Node"""

    pass


class Logos(SphinxDirective):
    """Logo directive to create a grid of logos from a json file

    Example:
        .. logo:: funder
    """

    has_content = True
    required_arguments = 1
    optional_arguments = 0
    final_argument_whitespace = False
    option_spec = {}

    def run(self) -> List[logo_node]:

        # get the env
        self.env

        # get the data
        data_dir = Path(__file__).parents[1] / "_data" / "logo"
        logo_file = data_dir / f"{self.arguments[0]}.json"
        logos = json.loads(logo_file.read_text())

        return [logo_node(logos=logos)]


def visit_logo_node_html(translator: SphinxTranslator, node: logo_node) -> None:
    """Entry point of the html logo node"""

    # Write the html content line by line for readability
    # init the html content
    html = '<div class="container my-4">\n'
    html += '\t<div id="funder-logos" class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">\n'

    for v in node["logos"].values():

        # get informations from the parameters
        size = SIZES[v["size"]]
        link = v["html"]
        light_logo = f"_static/logos/{v['light']}"
        dark_logo = f"_static/logos/{v['dark']}"

        # write the html files
        html += f'\t\t<div class="my-1 mx-2" style="width:{size}rem;">'
        html += f'<a href="{link}">'
        html += f'<img class="card-img only-light" src="{light_logo}">'
        html += f'<img class="card-img only-dark" src="{dark_logo}">'
        html += "</a>"
        html += "</div>\n"

    translator.body.append(html)


def depart_logo_node_html(translator: SphinxTranslator, node: logo_node) -> None:
    """exit from the html node and close the container"""

    translator.body.append("\t</div>\n</div>\n")


def visit_logo_node_unsuported(translator: SphinxTranslator, node: logo_node) -> None:
    """Entry point of the ignored logo node."""
    logger.warning("Logo: unsupported output format (node skipped)")
    raise nodes.SkipNode


def setup(app: Sphinx) -> Dict[str, bool]:
    app.add_node(
        logo_node,
        html=(visit_logo_node_html, depart_logo_node_html),
        epub=(visit_logo_node_unsuported, None),
        latex=(visit_logo_node_unsuported, None),
        man=(visit_logo_node_unsuported, None),
        texinfo=(visit_logo_node_unsuported, None),
        text=(visit_logo_node_unsuported, None),
    )
    app.add_directive("logos", Logos)

    return {
        "parallel_read_safe": True,
        "parallel_write_safe": True,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question trying to find the solution myself. I was able to get this to work for my use case where the `.rst` is importing/loading an object that is converted to an image on the fly. I dove into the docutils source and came up with this (a very slimmed down version of my actual code):

```py
from docutils import nodes


class MyDirective(SphinxDirective):

    required_arguments: int = 1

    def run(self) -> list[nodes.Node]:
        obj_import_path = self.arguments[0]
        obj_name = "test"
        img_path = f"_static/colormaps/{obj_name}.png"
        my_obj = _import_my_obj(obj_import_path)
        my_obj.save()

        paragraph = nodes.paragraph(text=obj_name)
        image = nodes.image("", **{"uri": img_path, "alt": obj_name})
        return [paragraph, image]
```

So this makes a "header" with the name of the object and then puts an image below it in the same way doing `.. image::` would. Note that the first argument to `nodes.image` is supposed to be the restructured text (ex. `.. image:: path/to/image.png`) but I found that things worked without it. You would use this by doing:

```
.. logos:: path/to/some.json
```

Note that in my actual code I allow for loading a list of these objects and since you're just returning a list of nodes there is no reason the single directive call can't handle it.